# Thunderbird doesn't download emails, despite my settings

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I want Thunderbird to download all emails automatically, as soon as as it opens. I use to to back up a Gmail account, by scheduling it to open, download everything, and close, periodically.

As mentioned, I use Gmail, using the standard set-up in Thunderbird. It defaults to using OAuth and it works fine. The only sub-folders are the ones from Gmail, including a few tags I set up via the web interface.

The mails appear in the folder when I click on it, but their content is not downloaded to offline storage. It seems to refresh headers when I click on the folder. The not downloaded ones seem to be more recent, but perhaps not the very most recent ones.

For some reason when I open Thunderbird it doesn't download all emails, despite my settings. I have tried:

- `mail.check_all_imap_folders_for_new` set to true
- `mail.server.default.check_all_folders_for_new` set to true
- "Keep all messages for this account on this computer" ticked
- "Synchronize all messages regardless of age" selected
- In the Advanced menu for synchronizing, all folders are ticked
- "Check for new messages at startup" ticked
- In Folder Properties -> "When getting new messages for this account, always check this folder" ticked
- In Folder Properties -> "Select this folder for offline use" ticked

If I manually click "Get Messages" it does download the messages.

I have Thunderbird 102.14.0 (64-bit). It is the portable version on Windows 10.

I have checked the following questions, but none of them offer any ideas I have not already tried:

- [How can I force Thunderbird to reload an IMAP folder structure from Outlook.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1791316/how-can-i-force-thunderbird-to-reload-an-imap-folder-structure-from-outlook-com)
- [Thunderbird fails to download all new emails](https://superuser.com/questions/977645/thunderbird-fails-to-download-all-new-emails)
- [How do I synchronize all folders and emails of an IMAP account locally with evolution?](https://superuser.com/questions/1292448/how-do-i-synchronize-all-folders-and-emails-of-an-imap-account-locally-with-evol)
- [Thunderbird won't download some emails](https://superuser.com/questions/1096065/thunderbird-wont-download-some-emails)
- [Sync or export only Thunderbird account settings](https://superuser.com/questions/969586/sync-or-export-only-thunderbird-account-settings)
- [How can I force Thunderbird to download all emails by IMAP?](https://superuser.com/questions/354280/how-can-i-force-thunderbird-to-download-all-emails-by-imap/354341#354341)

Comment: You should enhance your question by more details. At the first glance I miss (1) Do you use IMAP or POP3? (2) Do you maintain a sub-folder structure? (3) Which type of mails are missing? New noes or old ones? (4) By "*doesn't download everything"*, do you mean *"These mails are not listed."* OR *"The mail content hasn't been fetched, but you see it in the list"*? (5) How does this *"Open to download ... close"* look like?  How  is the scheduling done? (6) Surely there is more that would be good to know.

Comment: As explained in the question, I use Gmail via the built in support and default OAuth. I will add other details.